# Issues with PAX extended tar header

Tags: java

I have some issues regarding the extended PAX Tar header standard.

I wrote a program that reads a file header-by-header and prints some info, veryfing the ustar checksum in the process. Here is the output when I feed a PAX Tar to my program. It is written in Java.

```
run:
Reading at 0
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: .PKGINFO
Header is PAX: false
File size: 1055
Next header offset: 2048
--------------------------------------
Reading at 2048
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: .BUILDINFO
Header is PAX: false
File size: 8419
Next header offset: 11264
--------------------------------------
Reading at 11264
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: .INSTALL
Header is PAX: false
File size: 175
Next header offset: 12288
--------------------------------------
Reading at 12288
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: .MTREE
Header is PAX: false
File size: 4025
Next header offset: 16896
--------------------------------------
Reading at 16896
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 17408
--------------------------------------
Reading at 17408
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 17920
--------------------------------------
Reading at 17920
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/bin/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 18432
--------------------------------------
Reading at 18432
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 18944
--------------------------------------
Reading at 18944
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 19456
--------------------------------------
Reading at 19456
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/applications/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 19968
--------------------------------------
Reading at 19968
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
Header is PAX: false
File size: 13148
Next header offset: 33792
--------------------------------------
Reading at 33792
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 34304
--------------------------------------
Reading at 34304
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 34816
--------------------------------------
Reading at 34816
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 35328
--------------------------------------
Reading at 35328
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 35840
--------------------------------------
Reading at 35840
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 36352
--------------------------------------
Reading at 36352
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 36864
--------------------------------------
Reading at 36864
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 37376
--------------------------------------
Reading at 37376
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 37888
--------------------------------------
Reading at 37888
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 38400
--------------------------------------
Reading at 38400
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 38912
--------------------------------------
Reading at 38912
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/384x384/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 39424
--------------------------------------
Reading at 39424
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 39936
--------------------------------------
Reading at 39936
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 40448
--------------------------------------
Reading at 40448
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps/PaxHeader/firefox-symbolic.svg
Header is PAX: true
File size: 118
Next header offset: 41472
--------------------------------------
Reading at 41472
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/symbolic/apps/firefox-symbolic.svg
Header is PAX: false
File size: 6935
Next header offset: 49152
--------------------------------------
Reading at 49152
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/384x384/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 49664
--------------------------------------
Reading at 49664
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/384x384/apps/PaxHeader/firefox.png
Header is PAX: true
File size: 118
Next header offset: 50688
--------------------------------------
Reading at 50688
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/384x384/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 78972
Next header offset: 130560
--------------------------------------
Reading at 130560
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 131072
--------------------------------------
Reading at 131072
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/apps/PaxHeader/firefox.png
Header is PAX: true
File size: 118
Next header offset: 132096
--------------------------------------
Reading at 132096
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/192x192/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 30788
Next header offset: 163840
--------------------------------------
Reading at 163840
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 164352
--------------------------------------
Reading at 164352
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/PaxHeader/firefox.png
Header is PAX: true
File size: 118
Next header offset: 165376
--------------------------------------
Reading at 165376
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 17225
Next header offset: 183296
--------------------------------------
Reading at 183296
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 183808
--------------------------------------
Reading at 183808
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/PaxHeader/firefox.png
Header is PAX: true
File size: 118
Next header offset: 184832
--------------------------------------
Reading at 184832
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 6081
Next header offset: 191488
--------------------------------------
Reading at 191488
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 192000
--------------------------------------
Reading at 192000
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/PaxHeader/firefox.png
Header is PAX: true
File size: 118
Next header offset: 193024
--------------------------------------
Reading at 193024
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 44148
Next header offset: 238080
--------------------------------------
Reading at 238080
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 238592
--------------------------------------
Reading at 238592
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/PaxHeader/firefox.png
Header is PAX: true
File size: 118
Next header offset: 239616
--------------------------------------
Reading at 239616
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 4096
Next header offset: 244736
--------------------------------------
Reading at 244736
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 2472
Next header offset: 247808
--------------------------------------
Reading at 247808
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 248320
--------------------------------------
Reading at 248320
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 1327
Next header offset: 250368
--------------------------------------
Reading at 250368
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 250880
--------------------------------------
Reading at 250880
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 1319
Next header offset: 252928
--------------------------------------
Reading at 252928
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 253440
--------------------------------------
Reading at 253440
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/firefox.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 829
Next header offset: 254976
--------------------------------------
Reading at 254976
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/bin/firefox
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 255488
--------------------------------------
Reading at 255488
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 256000
--------------------------------------
Reading at 256000
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/gtk2/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 256512
--------------------------------------
Reading at 256512
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 257024
--------------------------------------
Reading at 257024
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/defaults/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 257536
--------------------------------------
Reading at 257536
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 258048
--------------------------------------
Reading at 258048
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 258560
--------------------------------------
Reading at 258560
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/PaxHeader/omni.ja
Header is PAX: true
File size: 87
Next header offset: 259584
--------------------------------------
Reading at 259584
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja
Header is PAX: false
File size: 9588234
Next header offset: 9848832
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9848832
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/dependentlibs.list
Header is PAX: false
File size: 38
Next header offset: 9849856
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9849856
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/application.ini
Header is PAX: false
File size: 419
Next header offset: 9850880
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9850880
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/platform.ini
Header is PAX: false
File size: 48
Next header offset: 9851904
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9851904
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/run-mozilla.sh
Header is PAX: false
File size: 8915
Next header offset: 9861632
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9861632
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/removed-files
Header is PAX: false
File size: 707
Next header offset: 9863168
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9863168
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/dictionaries
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 9863680
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9863680
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/hyphenation
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 9864192
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9864192
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/firefox-bin
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 9864704
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9864704
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/PaxHeader/libxul.so
Header is PAX: true
File size: 116
Next header offset: 9865728
--------------------------------------
Reading at 9865728
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
Header is PAX: false
File size: 71366624
Next header offset: 81232896
--------------------------------------
Reading at 81232896
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container
Header is PAX: false
File size: 454592
Next header offset: 81688064
--------------------------------------
Reading at 81688064
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/libmozgtk.so
Header is PAX: false
File size: 6000
Next header offset: 81694720
--------------------------------------
Reading at 81694720
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/firefox
Header is PAX: false
File size: 154800
Next header offset: 81850368
--------------------------------------
Reading at 81850368
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/liblgpllibs.so
Header is PAX: false
File size: 60272
Next header offset: 81911296
--------------------------------------
Reading at 81911296
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/webapprt-stub
Header is PAX: false
File size: 191792
Next header offset: 82103808
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82103808
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/0.1/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 82104320
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82104320
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/0.1/clearkey.info
Header is PAX: false
File size: 116
Next header offset: 82105344
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82105344
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/gmp-clearkey/0.1/libclearkey.so
Header is PAX: false
File size: 117480
Next header offset: 82223616
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82223616
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/webapprt.ini
Header is PAX: false
File size: 485
Next header offset: 82224640
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82224640
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/webapprt/omni.ja
Header is PAX: false
File size: 75149
Next header offset: 82300416
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82300416
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 82300928
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82300928
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/channel-prefs.js
Header is PAX: false
File size: 245
Next header offset: 82301952
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82301952
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 82302464
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82302464
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 82302976
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82302976
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 82303488
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82303488
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/components/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 82304000
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82304000
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 82304512
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82304512
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome.manifest
Header is PAX: false
File size: 40
Next header offset: 82305536
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82305536
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/PaxHeader/omni.ja
Header is PAX: true
File size: 88
Next header offset: 82306560
--------------------------------------
Reading at 82306560
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja
Header is PAX: false
File size: 12326304
Next header offset: 94633472
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94633472
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/blocklist.xml
Header is PAX: false
File size: 215251
Next header offset: 94849536
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94849536
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 94850048
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94850048
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 94850560
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94850560
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/defaults/preferences/vendor.js
Header is PAX: false
File size: 328
Next header offset: 94851584
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94851584
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/extensions/{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi
Header is PAX: false
File size: 3375
Next header offset: 94855680
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94855680
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/components/components.manifest
Header is PAX: false
File size: 36
Next header offset: 94856704
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94856704
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/components/libbrowsercomps.so
Header is PAX: false
File size: 60064
Next header offset: 94917632
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94917632
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/PaxHeader/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
Header is PAX: true
File size: 88
Next header offset: 94918656
--------------------------------------
Reading at 94918656
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/loop@mozilla.org.xpi
Header is PAX: false
File size: 1582541
Next header offset: 96501760
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96501760
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 96502272
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96502272
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 96502784
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96502784
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default16.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 829
Next header offset: 96504320
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96504320
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default32.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 2472
Next header offset: 96507392
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96507392
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/PaxHeader/default48.png
Header is PAX: true
File size: 88
Next header offset: 96508416
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96508416
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 4096
Next header offset: 96513536
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96513536
Verifying header checksum...
An tar error occured: Invalid Tar header checksum!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

At byte 96513536 I encouter this:

[image]

After some research i found that this is the PAX Extended header. The problem is this header is not annouced anywhere before it pops up.

How can I predict this header and handle it acordingly?

This is the output of a valid pass of my program.

```
run:
Reading at 0
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: Test1/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 512
--------------------------------------
Reading at 512
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: Test1/test_1
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 1024
--------------------------------------
Reading at 1024
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: Test2/
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 1536
--------------------------------------
Reading at 1536
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: Test2/Test_2
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 2048
--------------------------------------
Reading at 2048
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: test_3
Header is PAX: false
File size: 0
Next header offset: 2560
--------------------------------------
Reading at 2560
Verifying header checksum...
Invalid checksum, Tar EOF found.

Finnished reading, read 5 files and folders.
This took 15ms
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

How can i predict a PAX Header. How does PAX work at all? What are PaxHeader folders?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in my logic for calculating the next header.

```
Reading at 96508416
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
Header is PAX: false
File size: 4096
Next header offset: 96513536
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96513536
Verifying header checksum...
An tar error occured: Invalid Tar header checksum!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The file size is 4096 bytes. Here is the problem, my code looked originaly like this:

```
private void setOffsetToNextHeader(int size) {
        if (size == 0) {
            offset += 512;
        } else {
            offset += (((size + 512) / 512) + 1) * 512;
        }
    }
```

With this, the offset was set 512 bytes too much, because the algorithm relied on rounding down of the integer upon division by 512.

If there is no rouning happening, the result is multiplied one time too much by 512.

Changing the above code to this:

```
private void setOffsetToNextHeader(int size) {
        if (size == 0) {
            offset += 512;
        } else if ((size % 512) == 0) {
            offset += size + 512;
        } else {
            offset += (((size + 512) / 512) + 1) * 512;
        }
    }
```

Resolved the issue.

This is the valid output of the program that i was expecting:

```
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96508416
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
PAX Header prefix: false
File size: 4096
Next header offset: 96513024
Extracting...
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96513024
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/PaxHeader/mozicon128.png
PAX Header prefix: true
File size: 88
Next header offset: 96514048
Extracting...
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96514048
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/browser/icons/mozicon128.png
PAX Header prefix: false
File size: 17225
Next header offset: 96531968
Extracting...
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96531968
Verifying header checksum...
Checksum valid.
Found: usr/lib/firefox/gtk2/libmozgtk.so
PAX Header prefix: false
File size: 10096
Next header offset: 96542720
Extracting...
--------------------------------------
Reading at 96542720
Verifying header checksum...
Tar EOF found.

Finnished reading, read 109 files and folders.
This took 94ms
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find that

```
offset += ((size + 511) / 512) + 512;
```

covers all three cases of your `if/else if/else`.